# AdminLTE template css and js are placed in vendor folder so are unreachable from public folder

Tags: laravel-backpack

Version 3 of Backpack have all elements from AdminLTE on vendor folder, so CSS and JS are out of public folder.
I wonder if is there a way to process that with gulp in order to put them on public folder?

I think that following step by step installation from this page [https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/installation-on-laravel-53][1] everything is a little messy.

[image: files from backpack installation]

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 of the Backpack\Base installation process takes care of that for you. The [link you provided](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/installation-on-laravel-53) has this as a third step:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider" #publishes configs, langs, views and AdminLTE files    
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Prologue\Alerts\AlertsServiceProvider" # publish config for notifications - prologue/alerts
php artisan migrate #generates users table (using Laravel's default migrations)
```

Notice the first command will also copy the AdminLTE files from /vendor to /public.

Comment: Ohhhh shame on me! I must leave out some of these step.
I will try again with special care on it.
Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Cheers!